# How to select from pdbs with a cdb user?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, database-link

I have several store procedures, which analyze oracle logs using log miner. These procedures run on CDB user C##ADMIN which created for this manner.

Now I want to compare the logged values to the live values, so I need to be able to access each pdb from the CDB.

After several searches, I came across `database link` which looks like a possible answer. but when I'm trying to create a database link it says `ORA-02011: duplicate database link name`. and when I'm trying to drop it I'm getting `ORA-65230: internal database link cannot be altered or dropped`.

I'm tried to run the following queries, but it failed: (even when connected as: `/ as sysdba`)

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES@testpdb; 

ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
*Cause: The connection request could not be completed because the listener 
      is not running.
*Action: Ensure that the supplied destination address matches one of 
      the addresses used by the listener - compare the TNSNAMES.ORA entry with 
      the appropriate LISTENER.ORA file (or TNSNAV.ORA if the connection is to 
      go by way of an Interchange). Start the listener on the remote machine.

SELECT * FROM test.TABLE1@testpdb;   

ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
*Cause: The connection request could not be completed because the listener 
      is not running.
*Action: Ensure that the supplied destination address matches one of 
      the addresses used by the listener - compare the TNSNAMES.ORA entry with 
      the appropriate LISTENER.ORA file (or TNSNAV.ORA if the connection is to 
      go by way of an Interchange). Start the listener on the remote machine.
```

So my questions are:

- Is using database links is it the correct way?
- If it is, how to configure it?
- How can I use it?
- Do I have any alternative to achieve my goal?

Comment: see if one of these help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means your listener is not running. Start your listener.

This just works normally without doing anything:

```
SQL> create user c##myadmin identified by password;

User created.

SQL> grant dba to c##myadmin container=all;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> alter user c##myadmin set container_data=all container=current;

User altered.

SQL> conn c##myadmin/password
Connected.
SQL> select con_id, name from v$containers;

    CON_ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 CDB$ROOT
         2 PDB$SEED
         3 PDB1
         4 PDB2

SQL> select count(*) from dba_users@pdb1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        37

SQL> select count(*) from dba_users@pdb2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        37

SQL> select db_link from dba_db_links;

DB_LINK
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_HUB
```

An alternative is the [CONTAINERS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BCEGGHJC) clause, but that has some serious limitations (queried object must exist in all containers).