# Is it possible to select from procedure\function when the PDB is an argument without connect?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-19c

I have the following function in oracle 11g.

```
Create or Replace function get_col_value(
schema# in varchar2, 
table# in varchar2, 
column# in varchar2, 
rowid# in varchar2)
Return varchar2
Is
 v_cmd varchar2(2000)
 v_retval varchar2(32767)
BEGIN
Begin
 v_cmd := 'select "'||column#||'" from "'||schema#||'"."'||table#||'" Where "ROWID"='''||rowid#||'''';
 execute immediate v_cmd into v_retval;
EXCEPTION When others THEN
  NULL;
End
return ''''||v_retval||'''';
END
```

Now I'm trying to make it work on 19c (on CDB) with additional PDB parameter:

```
Create or Replace function get_col_value(
pdb#  in  varchar2, 
schema# in varchar2, 
table# in varchar2, 
column# in varchar2, 
rowid# in varchar2)
Return varchar2
Is
 v_cmd varchar2(2000)
 v_retval varchar2(32767)
BEGIN
Begin
 -- v_cmd := 'select "'||column#||'" from "'||schema#||'"."'||table#||'" Where "ROWID"='''||rowid#||'''';
 execute immediate v_cmd into v_retval;
EXCEPTION When others THEN
  NULL;
End
return ''''||v_retval||'''';
END
```

Can I do it without a 'connect' command?

I don't want to put the DBA password in a procedure/function, and I don't want to change the script every time I change the password.

Comment: This is the same question as https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283869/how-to-select-from-pdbs-with-a-cdb-user . With dynamic SQL you can use the PDB name as a dblink.

Comment: @BalazsPapp Without the creation of a DB link, I'm getting: `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener` (using sys as sysdba)

Comment: Then you have an issue with your environment. I repeat, this just works normally without doing anything. See my example in that question.